# error when running briefcase dev remotely over ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code

When running briefcase dev on my project which is on Ubuntu server 22.04 and which I access remotely via ssh from visual studio code I receive the following error report:

> RuntimeError: Cannot identify an active display. Is the `DISPLAY`
> environment variable set correctly?

I have tried several solutions that I have looked for but none of them solved my problem. Can you help resolve it?

Comment: @Scott Hunter I've already improved the question, the problem is I can't solve it. I think it is related to X11 routing. Can you help me resolve or truly identify where I'm going wrong?

Comment: As the stack trace asks, "Is the `DISPLAY` environment variable set correctly?"

Comment: @Scott Hunter Yes, but I've already researched this and I can't seem to resolve it. I always get this error. I was trying to find someone who could help me overcome this problem.